# Laravel DB connection issue on local network

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I serve my Laravel app on the local network with the following artisan command "sudo php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.102 --port 8080".

The app is accessible from the local network, however, when the app tries to handle a DB query it throws the following exception:

> could not find the driver (SQL: select * from `tests`)".

When I serve my app on localhost with a plain "php artisan serve" command DB queries work just fine, though.

What could cause the issue and how do I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: The following steps helped me solve the problem:

1) sudo apt install php-mysql
2) locate php.ini file with "php --ini" command
3) find and uncomment the following line ";extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll"
4) restart the server

I'm still confused as to why everything went fine when serving my app locally, though.